# How create second class and setTest to TextView?

Tags: java, android, class

I want create second class.
What incorrect in this code?
How get access to field "TextView"?

*MainActivity.java:*

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        my_class d = new my_class();
        d.my_method("ololo");
    }
}
```

*my_class.java:*

```
package mikevmf.my_class_mk;
import android.widget.TextView;
public class my_class extends MainActivity {
    public void my_method(String stroka){
        TextView my_text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.my_text);
        my_text.setText(stroka);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you extend your class with TextView not MainActivity

Comment: no, you do not need activity for your class. public class my_class extends TextView will do what you want.